# Compile error when assigning IQueryable<int> to IQueryable<object>

Tags: c#, covariance

Why the compiler doesn't allow to assign ints to objects?

```
IQueryable<object> objects = null;
IQueryable<int> ints = null;
objects = ints;
```

Comment: You can cast it to `IQueryable<ValueType>` (OR) cast it to `IQueryable<object>` before assigning.

Comment: What is the target framework of your project? Is it by any chance .NET framework 3.5 or older?

Comment: @elgonzo, I use .Net Framework 4.5.1

Comment: This is a duplicate, but for a practical answer to dealing with the issue, since you can assign an int to object, `objects = ints.Cast<object>();` would work if you actually needed such a queryable.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit type conversion (a function of covariance) does not apply to all generics. *SomeGeneric<ValueType>* is not derived from to *SomeGeneric<Reference>* and thus, it is not valid to cast it even if there is a already an implicit conversion for the type parameters (in this case, boxing).

If you are in C# 4.0, a generic interface can be defined as covariant using *ISomeGeneric<out T>* and provided that the generic arguments are *derived* from one another, then you can cast. If the generic arguments are not derived, it is not possible to cast.

Comment: Well, the type parameter of IQuerable<T> is covariant (i.e., `IQueryable<out T>`) according to its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx)... hmm...

Comment: Perhaps OP targets .NET 3.5 or older?

Comment: Check the edit I just made. Generic covariance does require that the type parameters are derivatives of each other. In the case of OP's question, Int does not inherit from Object and thus should not be convertible.

Comment: Ahh, you are right...

Comment: Int32 _does_ inherit from Object, as far as the actual type hierarchy is concerned (it's why you can box them), but value types can't participate in covariance (because you can't have a type argument of boxed int, at least not in anything but _maybe_ C++/CLI).